# How can I loop through an array

Tags: javascript, object, discord.js

I'm having problems with looping through an array. I'm making an RPG bot for Discord, and I need to display the `inventory` of the player when prompted. I've tried to use `Object.values()`, `Object.map()` and `Object.entries()`. The names of the `items` are already worked out with `Object.keys(inventory)`, but the `values` are the problem.

```js
var invItems = Object.keys(inventory);
var InvValues = Object.entries(inventory);
for (var i = 0; i <= invItems.length; i += 1) {
       if (invValues[i[1]] > 0) {
           message.channel.send(`${invValues[i[1]]}x ${invItems[i]}`);
       }
};
```

I'm a beginning coder, so please explain more detailed than you usually may do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send values to `message.channel` directly using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop like:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(inventory)) {
  if (value > 0) {
    message.channel.send(`${value}x ${key}`);
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs. So, when we use it like:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

console.log(Object.entries(object1));
```

You can we get get an array back and each inside array is another array of key-value pair. Now, we can get each key & value using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and `for...of` loop like:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// Returns:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"
```

You can see this now returns all the keys and values properly. We have to just modify it a little bit to match your requirement and send the required message back.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var invItems = Object.keys(inventory);
var invValues = Object.entries(inventory); // fixed the capital i

for (var i = 0; i <= invItems.length; i += 1) {

   if (invValues[i] > 0) {
       message.channel.send(`${invValues[i]}x ${invItems[i]}`);
   }
};
```

You are not using `i` as an index rather you are trying to access `i[1]` as if it were an array

also, in Javascript, you can also do a `JSON.stringify` to see the object structure. this will print your `inventory` to a `JSON String`.

```js
//this may help you see what the inventory looks like
for(let i = 0; i<inventory.length; i+=1)
console.log(JSON.stringify(inventory[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with `Object.entries` which will provide an array of key/value pair arrays. Note that here: `invValues[i[1]]` you are trying to access a property `1` of `i` with is probably `undefined`. You can actually avoid some complication if you iterate with `forEach` here.

```js
const inventory = {
  itemA: 'description for A',
  itemB: 'description for B'
}

Object.entries(inventory).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  // replace with message.channel.send(...)
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
})
```